# Add events from an external source in SharePoint

Tags: calendar

I want to add all the entries in an excel file on to my SharePoint Calendar through a workflow or any other method. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Does it need to be in an Excel spreadsheet? A list has almost the same properties as a spreadsheet. If you put the info into a list, you can use a calendar overlay to get it onto a calendar, or even just create a calendar view from the data in the list. It just needs to be time based ... start and stop points.

Comment: i get some data in an excel format , but i dont want to add them manually as it takes a lot of time so i jsut need to automate that.

Comment: how would i achieve what you are saying , i dont need the events in the excel sheet later on , so if i use calendar overlay i wont be able to delete the additional view which i am creating with the excel sheet or can i ?

Comment: You can cut and paste from an excel spread sheet as long as the columns are the same. Highlight and copy (control-c) the entire work book, then place your list in data sheet mode, place cursor in upper left corner, then (control-v) to paste entire contents into SP. Change back to normal mode, accept the wait if prompted and all data is now in SP. You don't need to delete the regular view after making a calendar view, but I believe you can without issue. Users can add events directly into SP without the need of a spreadsheet, as long as they have permissions.

Comment: ok , i will try that , could you please also let me know that if i need to add particular events from one calendar to another based on some condition , be it time based or say an approval as a matter of fact then how can i do that with a workflow in the designer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use use Access instead of Excel, then sync the calendar data with Access file.

Here are the detail steps:

1. Go to your calendar, then click Actions > Open with Access. Click OK on popup window, the Microsoft Access open.
2. Click Publish to SharePoint Site besides Publish Changes, and then select a document library to store the “.accdb” file, click Publish. Or save it to your local computer.
3. Edit the Access file we created in step2, save the file, then all changes will update to calendar list automatically.

We can Import data from Excel to the Access file  by right clicking the calendar table in Access > select Import from Excel